# multiple table select with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select

I have 'order' table that include order details like id,date and etc and a table 'order_products' that contain (order_id,product_id)

I want to make a SELECT that will return array that have an array inside with all the products id's

example: $array=(id,date,...,array products(id1,id2...))

This is my code:

```
public function get_order_single($id)
{
     $query = $this->db->select( '
                orders.id,
                orders.customer_id AS customerID,
                orders.date,
                orders.payment_method AS paymentMethod,
                orders.total_price AS totalPrice,
                orders.delivery_address AS address,
                orders.modified,
                orders.created')
                ->from( 'orders' )
                ->where('id',$id)
                ->get()
                ->result( 'array' );    
    return $query[0];
}
```

What I need to add to get all the info from the second table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function get_order_single($id)
{
    // Get your order
    $order = $this->db->select('
            orders.id,
            orders.customer_id AS customerID,
            orders.date,
            orders.payment_method AS paymentMethod,
            orders.total_price AS totalPrice,
            orders.delivery_address AS address,
            orders.modified,
            orders.created')
        ->from('orders')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->get()
        ->row();

    // If order is exists, lets find products for it
    if ($order) {
        // Here we do a join also to your pivot table
        $order->products = $this->db
            ->where_in('order_products.order_id', $order->id)
            ->join('order_products', 'order_products.product_id = products.id', 'left')
            ->get('products')
            ->result();
    }

    return $order;
}
```

Comment: I used objects, but you can change them to arrays: `row()` -> `row_array()`. `result()` -> `result_array()`. `$order->id` -> `$order['id']`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
$this->db->select('name, value'); // SELECT which columns you want
$this->db->join('attribute', 'attribute.id = product_attribute.attribute_id', 'left'); // JOIN 1st table
$this->db->join('attribute_value', 'attribute_value.attribute_id = product_attribute.attribute_id', 'left'); // JOIN 2nd table
$this->db->where('product_id', $id); // CONDITION
$query = $this->db->get('product_attribute'); // FROM clause
return $query->result();
```